# jpa sequence ID generation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

There is tremendous value to be obtained by assigning an ID to an entity before it is persisted to database but immediately in the constructor: your equals/hashcode implementation becomes trivial, [and it saves many headaches](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1).

I have seen problems when the entity equality is based on `==`: a proxy gets in the session and when it gets unwrapped as the real object, you get `equals()` that returns `false`.

And when you override `equals` and `hashcode` to use the generated ID, because that one is generated only on `persist()`, all non-persisted entities have id `null` and therefore are all equal to one another.

From what I read, when you use a traditional ID generation technique (autoincrement let's say), the ID is generated when the entity manager is flushed. When you use a sequence-based solution, it's generated at persist-time.

That article and my current understanding say the simplest solution is to assign an ID at creation-time, not persist or flush time. And with sequences that appears reachable, but JPA decided against it. With getting IDs being something cheap with sequences (as you can prefetch), how come JPA has not provided at least an option to obtain a sequence-based ID already at object construction time? There is a risk of wasting some IDs if the entity is not in fact persisted in the end, but I think it's not a big problem.

Barring that, the only "no compromises" as far as simplicity and understandability of the solution appear to be UUIDs, which have their own problems.

am I missing something? Is there maybe somewhere some JPA identity generator or some library that would be based on sequence and allow to give the ID at construction time?

Answer (score 2):

Using an [assigned identifier](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/) is the best approach from a writing perspective. It's also consistent across all [entity state transitions](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/) and you can even batch multiple inserts at JDBC level.

When it comes to reading and indexing, a numeric column performs better and an assigned identifier is either **unique logical key (Social Security Number)** or a unique identifier (e.g. UUID). Using application-level unique assigned identifiers is complicated because you may have multiple application nodes (in a cluster) or you want to synchronize inserts from both within the application as well as from external sources (database client utility).

For database-assigned identifier you need to take into consideration how flushing is affected by your choice. Hibernate tries to defer the [Persistence Context flushing up until the last possible moment](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/). This strategy has been traditionally known as transactional write-behind.

The write-behind is more related to Hibernate flushing rather than any logical or physical transaction. During a transaction, the flush may occur multiple times.

The flushed changes are visible only for the current database transaction. Until the current transaction is committed, no change is visible by other concurrent transactions.

[IDENTITY requires flushing](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/), while a sequence is non-transactional, hence it doesn't require a flush. IDENTITY disables JDBC insert batching and it doesn't support pre-allocation.

JPA cannot assign the identifier at Entity construct time, because a new instance can only become persisted through an EntityManager.persist() call. JPA requires explicit "entity state transitions".

Wasting a sequence identifier is not much of a problem. The database performs just fine even with gaps in sequence values. Using a bigint column can guarantee you don't practically run out of sequence identifiers. It's better to have non-transactional sequence identifier allocation with occasional gaps than to have transactional allocation with a higher risk of dead-lock contention.

Comment: I still don't get it. With a numeric type backed by a sequence, if you prefetch sequence values, you still get batched writes, you still get good indexing, you don't need flushing. In my limited understanding, I don't see a need to tie persisting and entity to assigning it an ID, so I don't see why not assigning a previously reserved sequence number as ID at construction time? Especially if waste is not a concern.

Comment: so, i would use prefetched sequence values instead of UUIDs, seems to me I get the plusses of UUIDs (minus ID generation on the client) without the performance and space concerns, but I don't find a ready-made solution (generator) for that, which surprises me.

Comment: that's very interesting! I didn't know about that. But will it let me get an id before the persist() call, which is my design simplicity concern (I understand the performance concerns that solves otherwise)?

Comment: Better benchmark both UUID and pooled-lo and see which option better suits your needs.